Why the new Stack Overflow Developer Survey charts do not render on Firefox correctly?
When opening results of the SO 2024 survey, charts are not rendered until window is shrunk a bit so that the chart dark gray frame shrinks as well. Another trigger to show the chart is to switch to another tab and back - charts will appear.


It must be some Svelte DOM updating issue causing it yet I tried disabling all extensions and it did not make any difference.
Running on the latest Arch Linux update from this week.

This has been reported previously on Meta Stack Overflow: "Filtered" graphs are initially blank.
